# Whats the simpelst way to split multiple paramters with query_string?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

**Im calling an agent with a URL like this:**

```
http://myserver/db.nsf/testagent?openagent&param1=ONE&param2=TWO
```

The agent '**testagent**' should get the value of paramter as fast as possible. I read that 'query_string' should do that, but the code gets very long, when I really want ONLY to get the values **ONE** and **TWO**. Is there a more simpler / faster way to get these values?

**My Lotus Script code looks like:**

```
Dim s As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim arg As String, p1 As Long

arg = s.DocumentContext.Query_String(0)
p1 = InStr(arg, "&")

If p1 = 0 Then
    Print "ERROR: No arugment."
    Exit Sub
Else
    arg = LCase(Mid$(arg, p1 + 1))
    ' (more code): Split again the ARG to & (more code)
    ' (more code): Split the values again to =, after that fill the 2 element as param 1 (ONE) and param 2 (TWO)
End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the answer already in the title of your question: just split the string...

In addition I usually use lists for this kind of tasks as they are easy and fast to access. I‘d take that out as a separate function to be able to reuse the code and make everything better readable:

```
Function GetQuerystringParameters( strQueryString as String ) as Variant
  Dim varParams as Variant
  Dim lstrParams List as String
  varParams = Split( strQueryString, "&")
  Forall strParam in varParams
    If Instr(strParam, "=") > 0 then
      lstrParams( strtoken( strParam, "=", 1))= strtoken( strParam, "=", 2)
    End If
  End ForAll
  GetQuerystringParameters = lstrParams
End Function
```

Now you can simply get the right parameter and Parameters need not even be in the right order:

```
Dim urlParams as Variant
Dim yourArg as String
urlParams = GetQuerystringParameters( arg )
If isElement( urlParams( "param1" ) ) then
  yourArg = urlParams( "param1" )
Else
  Print "Error: no param1"
  Exit Sub
End If
```

Hope that helps.

Edit: I would probably even make a class from this to further reduce code and make it even better reusable:

```
Class UrlParameters
  Private lstrParams List as String
  Sub New( strQueryString as String )
    Call Me.GetParameters( strQueryString )
  End Sub
  Private Sub GetParameters( strQs as String )
    Dim varParams as Variant
    varParams = Split( strQs, "&")
    Forall strParam in varParams
      If Instr(strParam, "=") > 0 then
        Me.lstrParams( strtoken( strParam, "=", 1)) = strtoken( strParam, "=", 2)
      End If
    End ForAll
  End Sub
  Function getUrlParameter( strParam as String ) as String
    If Iselement(Me.lstrParams(strParam)) then
      getUrlParameter = Me.lstrParams(strParam)
    Else
      GetUrlParameter = ""
    End If
  End Function
End Class
```

You could use this class like that:

```
Dim myParams as UrlParameters
Set myParams = New UrlParameters( arg )
param1 = myParams.getUrlParameter("param1")
param2 = myParams.getUrlParameter("param2")
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering - thanks a lot, it helps a lot..

Comment: At line `Me.lstrParams( strtoken( strParam, "=", 1) = strtoken( strParam, "=", 2)` there is a error message: `Not a sub or function name` - Even I put a ')' in the end, its still not working well, whats missing?

Comment: The missing ')' is right before the '=', but if you don‘t find that out yourself, then you don‘t understand what the code does and should probably not use it... but that‘s just my humble opinion....

Comment: Thank you, everything is fine. There are some functions that are new for me, but this is no reason to not to learn them and than also not to use it. Don't worry, thank you! :-)

Comment: OK. I'm sorry that I forgot my usual disclaimer: Code I post here is typed down in the browser. No autocomplete, no syntax check, no guarantee that it works... Use it just as boilerplate for the real solution.

Answer (score 0):

For fast and simple, try using basic string handling on the DECODED version of the query string:

```
'Get the decoded query string value and extract p1 and p2
arg = s.DocumentContext.Query_String_Decoded(0)
p1 = StrRight(arg, "param1=")
If instr(p1, "&") Then p1 = StrLeft(p1, "&")
p2 = StrRight(arg, "param2=")
If instr(p2, "&") Then p2 = StrLeft(p1, "&")
```

So p1="ONE" and p2="TWO". The decoded CGI variable should take care of any character encoding for you. (If you don't use this either write your own decoder or never use non-alpanumeric characters in your parameters).

Of course you can abstract this out to a function, but you'll lose a bit of speed, and a function isn't really needed unless you have a lot of parameters:

```
Function GetParam(arg, px) as astring
    GetParam = StrRight(arg, px & "=")
    If instr(GetParam, "&") Then GetParam = StrLeft(GetParam, "&")
End Function
```

Then simply call it:

```
arg = s.DocumentContext.Query_String_Decoded(0)
p1 = GetParam(arg, "param1")
p2 = GetParam(arg, "param2")
```

There's nothing wrong with putting params in a List, but its rare you have to reuse a parameter once its parsed out and although lists are fast, they add overhead and complexity.